# Add multi page text box in Crystal Reports 2013

Tags: crystal-reports, textbox, crystal-reports-2013

We have a multi-page Terms and Conditions which needs to print out at then end of our Quotes.  I created a single row text box and pasted it in. I tried it in Page Footer a and well as Page Footer b.  I formatted the text box: Can Grow with all the other boxes unchecked. I can scroll down through it to see it is all there in the text box, but when I View Preview it doesn't expand beyond one page.  How can I make it grow into multiple pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when placed in the Report Footer b section.